# what's ".browse.c_cpp.db" in .vscode used for

Tags: visual-studio-code, platformio

I have some project folders (it's platformIO project) create by *VSCode*, Everyone of these got a `.browse.c_cpp.db` in .vscode folder. and it's very big size(about 100mB). and because I need sync these folder with cloud so it's too big for me, so if I can disable it.

[image: file stats of the browse.c_acpp.db]

Comment: What do you mean by "sync these folders with cloud"?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I guess he means to push/upload the project.

Comment: @jianshan I think this is caused by the c/c++ vscode extension. Here is a [thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1234) which might give you more info.

Comment: If the project is "synced to the cloud" using git or any other source control tool, ignore that file, remove it from your repository if you have already committed. If "syncing to the cloud" means things like Dropbox or similar, you're out of luck, unless you can configure whatever makes this file to not make this file. BTW you probably shouldn't use dropbox or similar to sync your projects.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Hi thank you for your reply, I need sync my project files between  2 computers with onedrive. and it have only 5GB for free so I need reduce the size of these folders. The point is how can I disable these large files...

Comment: @ Dan Macák thank you, I'll check it out.

Comment: unfortunately it's not git, I'm not sure if it can ignore files...

Comment: So your question isn't "what are these files", it's "how can I stop vscode from creating these files".

Comment: Additionally, any reason *why* you're not just using git to synchronize this? Using dropbox, onedrive, google drive (stream), etc. might eventually lead to inconsistencies, if  you manage to edit the project on one computer before it has fully been synchronized from another computer, then you'll have conflicts. In other words, my recommendation on how to fix your issue would be to switch to using git, set up a free account on github and use a private repository there to synchronize your project.